# Regexp: 0.50 to 100.00

Tags: javascript, html, regex

How can I make a regular expression that only allows values from **0.50** up towards **100.00**. However you should only be able to add 0.50 between every rounded number.

**For example:** 12.50 or 12.5

**Not:** 42.1 or 1.35

Regular expressions is some of the hardest things I've encountered in my coding experience so far. That's why I'm posting here to understand It's complexity and learn more about how it works.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: It's possible to use a RegEx for this (and I would suggest an online regex tool for doing this) but this seems like something that would be better done and simpler using JavaScript. Specifically not allowing `0.00` would make the regex far more complicated.

Comment: Maybe `^(0.50|(?:[1-9]\d?|[2-9]\d)(?:\.50)?|100\.00)$`, I'd prefer to compare it is an int though.. You could check the `100.00` or `0.50` first, then if not a match replace `.50` with `''` and check `>= 1` && `<= 100`. Integer ranges in regex never go well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?  `^(?:(?:\d|[1-9]\d)\.[05]0?|100\.00?)$`

You could replace anchors with word boundary's `\b` if needed.

Explained

```
 ^                    # BOS
 (?:
      (?:                  #=
           \d                   # 0-9
        |                     # or,
           [1-9] \d             # 10-99
      )                    #=
      \. [05] 0?           # .0 or .5   +   optional 0

   |                     # or, 

      100\.0 0?            # 100.0   +   optional 0
 )
 $                    # EOS
```

If you want to make the decimal portion optional it's this
`^(?:(?:\d|[1-9]\d)(?:\.[05]0?)?|100(?:\.00?)?)$`

Explained

```
 ^                        # BOS
 (?:
      (?:                      # Required
           \d                       # 0-9
        |                         # or,
           [1-9] \d                 # 10-99
      )
      (?: \. [05] 0? )?        # Optional   .0 or .5 +  optional 0

   |                         # or, 

      100                      # Required 100 
      (?: \.0 0? )?            # Optional   .0 + optional 0
 )
 $                        # EOS
```

Answer (score 1):

`const number = 0.5;
/0\.50|0\.5|^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\.[5 | 50 | 0]|100\.0/.test(number);`

Check string if 0.5 or 0.50 or
A number 1-9 or a number 10-99 with .5 .50 or .0 or
100.0
https://repl.it/GX4l/0

I am not sure why you would want to do this with a regex though. You have to do a lot of work to rewrite the regex if you want to change the range. You can just test the range and see if it is a multiple of .5
`someNumber >= .5 && someNumber <= 100 && someNumber%.5 == 0`

Comment: Not criticizing, just pointing out why regex is such a bad soltion: This fails in so many ways (it accepts `33.`, fails on `100` or `100.00` and several more). To make sure that you cover every possibility is hard.

Comment: It matches `1234560.5` or `1.|` or `1.567890123`